# Animate a flexible Div inside a Div

Tags: html, css, animation

im trying to animate a logoslider just with CSS3.

I tried to animate a div-container, which has an unknown amount of logos inside (cms), inside its wrapper. I tried this by using a `margin-left:0` => `margin-left:-100%`
The problem is, that the inner Div is using the parentdiv's (wrapper) width and not its own...

I made a fiddle for better understanding:

http://jsfiddle.net/gb0q3j37/

```css
#wrapper {
    width:500px;
    height: 85px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#slider ul{
 white-space: nowrap;
 animation: slider 10s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: slider 10s linear infinite;
    
}

#slider li {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background: #a5fc2a;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}


@-webkit-keyframes slider {
    0%   {margin-left: 0%}
    50%  {margin-left:-100%}
    100%  {margin-left: 0%;}
}

@keyframes slider {
    0%   {margin-left: 0%}
    50%  {margin-left:-100%}
    100%  {margin-left: 0%;}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
            <li>9</li>
            <li>10</li>
            <li>11</li>
            <li>12</li>
            <li>13</li>
            <li>14</li>
            <li>15</li>
            <li>16</li>
            <li>17</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gb0q3j37/

Any help? :)

Greetings

Phil

Comment: *"..the inner Div is using the parentdiv's (wrapper) width and not its own.."*: You have not specified inner `div` width at all. Specify width for `div#slider`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gb0q3j37/1/

Comment: Hi, i can't specify the width, because i don't know the amount and the width of li's. Thats exactly the problem. Your fiddle doesn't work at all...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gb0q3j37/2/

Comment: Now this is working! THANK YOU!!! Any idea how i get this slider not to slide 100% out of the viewport? margin-left:-99% or something like this, wont work because of the dynamic width...

Comment: *EDIT: Problem solved! http://jsfiddle.net/gb0q3j37/3/ <= with fix for the correct slidewidth :)